# Nodes on force graph links in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I am trying to create a force graph with nodes on the links between main nodes (O--o--O), similar to this visualization: http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2013/02/20/movies/among-the-oscar-contenders-a-host-of-connections.html:

[image]

More specifically, I would like the links between nodes to start and stop at a main node (O), with a link node (o) at the midpoint. Is there a straightforward way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Generally: Create two classes or categories of nodes ("main", "midpoint") in your network data structure and conditionally set a node's radius and other style attributes based on class membership.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to do that, but is it best to fix the midpoint nodes and manually place each node to the right place for each tick? Or can the midpoint nodes be part of the force simulation but displaced?

Comment: For simplicity's sake, I would first try to treat a "midpoint" node as just another node, but style it differently than "main" nodes. You could also conditionally adjust the force calculation based on the node type, so that "midpoint" nodes behave differently than "main" nodes.

Comment: The issue I am having is how to get the curved path to go "through" the midpoint node, i.e. the path not starting at a main node and stopping at a midpoint node.